# Trying to generate axis2 client stub for given WSDL

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I am trying to generate axis2 client stub for given WSDL but getting following error-

```
[ERROR] java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 15:
file:/C:/Pluton Server/installers/Webservice
_engine/axis2-1.5.1/bin/EncryptService.wsdl
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path 
at   index 15: 
file:/C:/Pluton Server/installers/Webservice_engine/axis2-1.5.1/bin/EncryptService.wsdl
```

Comment: While I upvoted for the usefulness of the question, please try to format your code so that not just machines can read and understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by spaces in the path of the WSDL file's location: 
file:/C:/Pluton Server/installers/Webservice _engine/axis2-1.5.1/bin/EncryptService.wsdl

Try to move the WSDL file to a path that has no spaces (eg. c:/test/EncryptService.wsdl).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like URLs with spaces in them aren't allowed, which is no surprise. Either put the wsdl in a directory without spaces in the name or properly escape the path.